# Merging Div and Image

Tags: css, html, image, collision

I'm having some trouble placing the div that contains my heading (Prestige Worldwide HMC, The First Word in Entertainment) right next to my image. It seems that the image, due to its dimensions, is colliding with my heading and pushing it down. Is there any way I can move the div over the right side of the image to sit on the same line?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebsiteMain.css">
    <title>Prestige Worldwide HMC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">R&D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F.A.Q.</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="mainbody">
        <div id="bodycontainer">
            <div id="logolevel">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://www.mysoti.com/img/user/kongo/product/web/894875/894875_show_default.png"/>
                    </a>
                    <div id="Name">
                        <p>Prestige Worldwide HMC</p>
                        <p>The First Word In Entertainment</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and WebsiteMain.css:

```
* {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

/* HEADER */

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

#menu {
    width: 57%;
    margin: auto;
}

#menu li {
    margin-right: 8%;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #003a63;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: #003a63;
}

a:hover {
    color: #78a22f;
}

/* MAIN BODY */

body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#mainbody {
    background: #f2f9fe; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 0%, #d6f0fd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f2f9fe), color-stop(100%,#d6f0fd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 0%,#d6f0fd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 0%,#d6f0fd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f9fe 0%,#d6f0fd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f2f9fe 0%,#d6f0fd 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f9fe', endColorstr='#d6f0fd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#logo a img {
    margin-left: 14%;
    margin-top: -3%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

#Name {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-top: ;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#Name p:first-child {
    font-size: 500%;
    color: #003a63;
}

#Name p:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-top: ;
    color: #78a22f;
}
```

Comment: Typically you'll just want to post the problem, not everything. In your case you are posting everything through dropbox. I'd suggest either creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the problem or posting the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have an image, and a heading that you want next to each other. That is the question. Your image is super huge – with tons of white space. You should crop it down to the actual size of the image. That doesn't make any sense.

The relevant html is:

```
<a href="#" class="company-logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</a>

<div class="name">
    <p>Something Something yeah</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla etc etc etc.</p>
</div>
```

[fiddle 01](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/s45ub/1/)

Shows how block level elements act. (divs, p, etc. are `display: block` by default)
They are width 100% by default, so they push one another to the next line. This is normal.

[fiddle 02](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/s45ub/2/)

Shows these 'display: block' level elements floating left, which brings them to the same line (as long as their combined width isn't wider than the screen... in which case, again, they will push each other to the next line

[fiddle 03](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/s45ub/3/)

Shows the elements as `display: inline-block` and vertically aligned to each other with `vertical-align: middle' - you can't have these elements floating or they will still act like block elements and wont follow your inline-block rules, so you may need to put float: none; if you are in a responsive context where you have them floated in another circumstance.

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense to me now!

Comment: I'm glad. As a side note, I suggest you use class names instead of ID's basically, always. Save those for javascript interaction. :)

Answer (score 0):

change your css to this

```
#logo a img {
    margin-top: -3%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

and this

```
#Name {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-top: ;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I'm trying to keep the logo below the home button. Essentially, I want my webpage to somewhat resemble this website: http://webwiseone.com/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your bug and created a jsBin here: http://jsbin.com/ziwebico/1/.  I made some small changes to your css and mainly added this:

```
#logo a
{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: This kinda cancels itself in a way. Once an inline-block element is floated, it acts like a block element and no longer reacts to inline types of rules like vertical-align: middle etc. Not that it wont' fix the problem, but might as well be block.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! Unfortunately, I still need the logo to fall underneath the home button, and to resemble this website: http://webwiseone.com/.